# How to make an AJAX request when page finishes loading, that is triggered by window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have an event listener like so

```
function navBtn() {
$('#navBtn').on('click', (event) => {
    window.location.href = 'someotherfile.html';
    myAJAXrequest();
})
}
```

The problem it seems is that since the event listener is a click, they both get triggered. But by the time I get sent to the other page, the AJAX request never happens. Not sure how to redirect to another page by clicking a button, when that page has content that is added using an AJAX call, that doesn't occur. Is there a way to check if the new page I'm directing to loads first, before triggering the AJAX?

Comment: why don't you run the ajax call first, and then redirect to the new page in the callback?

Comment: `myAJAXrequest` is never called, since a new document is loaded. Even calling it before loading a new page won't help, in that case the pending AJAX call would be cancelled (unless you'd redirect in the AJAX callback). See [navigator.sendBacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) for a possible solution.

Comment: Can you share what `myAJAXrequest()` looks like? We might be able to give you some direction as to how to restructure your code to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the setTimeout function it will delay the redirection for some time and in that time your ajax will be executed. Here is the sample code.

```
function navBtn() {
        $('#navBtn').on('click', (event) => {
            myAJAXrequest();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = 'someotherfile.html';
            }, 3000)
        })
    }
```

here I have given a delay of 3 secs, you can increase or decrease the delay as you like.

Answer (score 0):

try to make  "myAJAXrequest()" async function

```
async function myAJAXrequest(){}; 

function navBtn() {

$('#navBtn').on('click', (event) => {

    await myAJAXrequest();

    window.location.href = 'someotherfile.html';  
})
}
```